Verilog problem with sensitivity list and multiple clocks
I asked this a couple weeks ago and got no answers.   I have now solved it, but I do not understand why the solution works.
I need to use multiple clocks in the sensitivity list of an always block, but do different things depending on which clock.  Last time I was dinged for not being specific enough, so I am enclosing a minimum complete code example.   As the comments state, I am trying to feather the turn on of 80 output bits, but need to change the rate at different points in the count (these are gate drive signals for a high voltage pulse modulator).
The code below is complete.  I am synthesizing this and running on a Lattice MachXO27000HC6TG144C.  For my testing, clk[1] is 100 MHz, clk[2] is 50 MHz.
module top (clk,run,cmd,tx);
                     purpose:  feather the turn-on of TX bits
                     from 1-5 turn on at clk[1] edges
                     from 6-10 turn on at clk[2] edges

    input wire [2:1] clk;       // external clocks
    input wire run, cmd;        // external RUN & CMD
    output reg [80:1] tx;       // output bits
    reg [7:1] count;        // counts from 1 to 80
    reg [2:1] eclk;         // clocks ANDed with combinatorial logic
    reg kludge;                         // *** uncomment for case2
    integer i;
    
    always @(posedge clk[1], negedge clk[1]) begin
        if (count <= 7'd5)  eclk[1] <= clk[1];
        else                 eclk[1] <= 1'b0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk[2], negedge clk[2]) begin
        if (count > 7'd5)   eclk[2] <= clk[2];
        else                 eclk[2] <= 1'b0;
    end
    
    always @* kludge <= eclk[1] | eclk[2];              // *** uncomment for case2
    
    always @(posedge kludge, negedge run, negedge cmd) begin          // *** use for case2
    always @(posedge eclk[1], posedge eclk[2], negedge run, negedge cmd) begin  // *** use for case1
    if (~run | ~cmd) begin
            tx <= 80'b0;
            count <= 7'b0; 
        end
        else begin
            if (count < 7'd10) count <= count + 7'd1;
            for (i=1; i<=80; i=i+1) begin
                tx[i] <= (count >= i);
            end
        end
    end  
endmodule


Rather than enclose two code snippets, the above has both working and non-working code for your entertainment.
For case1, which does not work, comment out two lines that define the variable "kludge", and use the case1 version of the final always block.  for case2, which does work, uncomment the two lines with kludge and use the case2 version of the final always block.
It appears that having both "posedge eclk[1], posedge eclk[2]" does not funcion the same as the single "posedge kludge" which is the "OR" of the above two (by design, the two eclks cannot be on simultaneously).   The function should be identical either way, but it definitely only works with the kludge in case2.
I can find nothing in any online documentation or textbook telling me of limits to sensitivity lists that would explain this.  Help?

Your uncomment comments do not make sense. Use `ifdef `else `endif to enclose the exact scenarios you want

As I recall, you never told us that the two clocks are mutually exclusive. That's the only reason your kludge works.

The more I read through your code, the less I can figure out what you are actually tying to accomplish. If you want an answer beyond "you're doing it wrong", you'll need to try and explain what you are actually trying to accomplish rather than how you think you need to make it.

Given you are trying to make something synthesisable for FPGAs (rather than random stuff for simulation), the standard rules for synthesis apply. You need to consider what hardware your code will infer.
FPGAs usually do not have registers capable of being sensitive to multiple clock edges. Given these registers are the building blocks for your design, this is a restriction you have no choice but to work with.
The following code is what the synthesis tools use to infer a register:
always @ (<pos|neg>edge clock [or <pos|neg>edge reset) begin
    if ([~]reset) begin
        q <= 0; // Action in reset. Either synchronous (not in list) or asynchronous (in list).
    end else begin
        q <= d; // Action when not in reset
    end
end

Anything else is for all intents and purposes illegal. You should not try to add multiple clocks to the sensitivity list (the registers are single edge), and you should not add multiple resets the to sensitivity list (they pretty much universally only have one).
In other words if your sensitivity list has more than two entries, you are doing it wrong. If it has more than one clock, you are doing it wrong.

As to what your code is doing. The case 1 will simply not synthesise. You have more than one clock. The tools do not know how to infer logic from this, hence it will produce an error.
The case 2 example, you only have one clock. Granted it is a logical combination of two clocks (*), but there is only one clock in the sensitivity list, so the tools know how to wire it up.
In your case 2, you also have two resets, which is strictly speaking wrong. But the synthesis tools may be a bit more lax about that, and manage to match it up with the if (~run | ~cmd) statement. Not all versions of all tools will correctly do this. You are much better off merging the resets externally.
You also have statements like always @(posedge clk[2], negedge clk[2]) begin which again is two clocks, so I have no idea how that synthesised properly (if it did).

The issue with your "kludge" approach, even with mutually exclusive clocks, is that FPGAs typically have two types of routing, the low skew clock pathways, and higher skew data pathways. By adding in an OR gate like this, you are forcing the clock to be routed on the latter pathways, which will result in a timing headache.
It is also extremely risky in that if the "disabled" clock ever goes high for any reason, you may produce a horrible clock glitch or inhibit the other clock, either of which could lead to metastability issues. Given you are using a counter to select which clock is enabled, this is a highly likely scenario, as you can't necessarily guarantee what state the clock is in when it switches over.

(*) Given you have stated your clocks are mutually exclusive, the below doesn't apply, but I'll keep it for completeness.
If your clocks were not mutually exclusive, this or'ed clock would be a horrible glitchy mess. Some possible following resulting clocks from the OR of a 50Mhz and 100MHz clock signal. This very much depends on the phase of the clocks, which you have limited control over, especially given they will have to be routed as data lines to be able to be OR-ed together:

Notice how if the phase is even slightly off, you get complete garbage.

Anyway, to answer your actual question:

Logical OR of two signals creates an actual hardware gate, or the equivalent function buried in a LUT.
An always block can be activated by any of a list of events — one or more expressions that denote a particular moment (or set of moments) in time. posedge clk1 is an example of an event, posedge clk2 is another event. Putting multiple expressions in the sensitivity list creates the union of all of the events from each expression.

The logical OR of two signals is not in any way equivalent to the union of two sets of events associated with those signals, and that's why synthesis tools treat them very differently. The only reason your kludge works is that you have the (previously unstated) external condition that the two clocks are mutually-exclusive.

Thank you (and others) for reading and trying to help.   I thought I explained what I was doing in the comments.  I have 80 output bits that go to gate drives on a high voltage pulse modulator.  I need to "feather" the leading edge of the pulse to damp out ringing from circuit inductance.  Modeling shows that I need to break this ramp into two or more segments with different slopes.   Thus this code will turn on the gates one at a time, first 5 of them at clock1 rate, then 5 more at clock2 rate.  How can I do this without offending the fundamentals of Verilog and FPGAs?

Wow, there's a lot of detail there I've never seen before. The obvious answer is to use two separate processes (i.e., always blocks). The first process drives the first five gates using clock1, and the second process drives the next five gates using clock2. In fact, just a couple of shift registers could do the job.

Hi Dave - yes, that works, but I need to be able to change N and M between shots (load via SPI from a CPU).   What you say is clean and robust, but the values N and M are hard coded.

I hope you understand why it's difficult and frustrating to work like this. You just introduced yet another hidden requirement. In your sample code, and all of the text/comments leading up to this point, the constant '5' is hard-coded. I assume that 'N' and 'M' refer to the number of gates associated with each of the clocks?
